# Regarding teams onlinemeeting schedule api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

While integrating onlinemeeting schedule api using microsoft graph

schedule api `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings`

Used to call api using token generated from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant id/oauth2/v2.0/token`

Getting below response but its working fine in `https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer`

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "Forbidden",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "b0a472d0-1658-480b-b41f-855bbe87b705",
        "date": "2021-05-12T18:55:15",
        "client-request-id": "b0a472d0-1658-480b-b41f-855bbe87b705"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How are you getting the token here? Share the code of how you are getting the token and also put your access token which you got in https://jwt.ms and see if there are required permission in it.

Comment: Getting token from this api

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token',
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('client_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXX','scope' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default','client_secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXX','grant_type' => 'client_credentials'),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'host: login.microsoftonline.com'
  ),
));

Comment: jwt.ms response

  "roles": [
    "AccessReview.ReadWrite.Membership",
    "User.ReadWrite.All",
    "AccessReview.ReadWrite.All",
    "Group.ReadWrite.All",
    "User.Read.All",
    "AccessReview.Read.All",
    "Chat.Create"
  ],

Comment: You need to have the permission Onlinemeetings.readwrite.all and also please create application access policy as said [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions). The call is working in graph explorer because there is a user logged in for graph explorer but using curl you are getting the token without logging in which is a application context flow. If you use this token then you should not use the call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings because there is no meaning of `me`.

Comment: So you should use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userid/onlineMeetings

Comment: I echo the same what's suggested by @ShivaKeshavVarma above. Try the same and see if it helps you to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, you’ll need to have the global admin execute some powershell to activate your application to allow to create online meetings for all/some users.

I’m just wondering what your use case is, for creating just the online meeting without a calendar event?

You can just do the same by creating an event in the users’ calendar and setting that you want an online meeting attached. That way only needs access to the users calendar and doesn’t need some special policy. Additionally the item with join button is right there in the users calendar.